# jQuery AJAX send search criteria to PHP return JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to send a group of variables to a PHP script via AJAX.

Typically, this is what I'd do:

```
 $('.submitSearch').on('click', function()
 {
   var rep = $('#rep').val();
   var num = $('#num').val();
   var uid = $('#uid').val();
   // and so on
   // then I could send each variable to a PHP script
   $.post('api/summary.php', {rep: rep, num: num, // and so...}, function(data)
   {
     console.log(data);
   });
 });
```

That's how I'd normally do it.

But now, I am trying send all of the parameters in a single variable I calling **searchCriteria**, as follows:

```
 $('.submitSearch').on('click', function()
 {
   var searchCriteria = 
   {
     rep: $('#rep').val(),
     num: $('#num').val(),
     uid: $('#uid').val(),
     // and so on...
   }

   // then send them to the php script

   $.post('api/summary.php', searchCriteria, function(data)
   {
     console.log(data);
   });
 });
```

Then, in the PHP script, retrieve all of the parameters from the variable for processing:

```
 <?php
  if($_POST['searchCriteria'] == true)
  {
    // get the parameters
    // build the query
    // return JSON
  } 

  ?>
```

My question is:  How do I get all of the parameters out of **$_POST['searchCriteria']** in the PHP script?

Comment: If you send it like this, you don't get a searchCriteria param on the PHP side but `rep`and `num` and `uid`.

Comment: Just wrap it in a bigger object {searchCriteria : searchCriteria} and then you'll retrieve it with $_POST['searchCriteria']

Comment: And if you do as @Carlos2W says, use `json_decode` to convert the JSON data to a PHP array or object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want everything in a single `$_POST` parameter, you need to wrap in another object:

```
$.post('api/summary.php', {searchCriteria : searchCriteria }, function(data) {
    ...
});
```

In the PHP, you would then access them as nested arrays.

```
$sc = $_POST['searchCriteria']
$rep = $sc['rep'];
$num = $sc['num'];
$uid = $sc['uid'];
```

I'm not sure what you expect to gain by adding this extra level of wrapping.

Comment: Wow!!!  This worked for me.  All I was trying to do was write less code, and this should help me out greatly.  Thank you, sir.

Comment: How is this less code than just sending `searchCriteria` by itself and then accessing `$_POST['rep']`?

Comment: This will only works if he knows in advance what are the search criterias. But yes, this is kind of useless wrapping if he only wants to get these.

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping it in a bigger object like this :

Javascript :

```
$('.submitSearch').on('click', function()
 {
   var searchCriteria = 
   {
     rep: $('#rep').val(),
     num: $('#num').val(),
     uid: $('#uid').val(),
    // and so on...
   }

   // then send them to the php script

   $.post('api/summary.php', {searchCriteria : searchCriteria }, function(data)
   {
     console.log(data);
    });
 });
```

PHP :

```
<?php
  if($_POST['searchCriteria'] == true)
  {
    $searchCriteria = json_decode($_POST['searchCriteria']);
    // Now you can for each loop throught it for example
    foreach($searchCriteria as $key => $value) {
       // Do something
    }
  } 

 ?>
```

Comment: Would you mind showing me how I use **$value** to access one of the parameters?  For instance, how would I echo **rep** using $value?

Comment: Why are you using `json_decode()`? You didn't call `JSON.stringify(searchCriteria)` in the Javascript.